# LDAP Query, get all Users from different OU's (with the same name)

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I have the following Active Directory structure:

```
example.com
    Organisation
        CompanyA
            Users
            SharedMailboxes
        CompanyB
            Users
            SharedMailboxes
        CompanyC
            Users
            SharedMailboxes
```

Inside each "Users" OU are User objects stored. I only want all the User objects  from the all the "Users" OU's. Note: The SharedMailboxes OU's also contain User objects, I don't want them.

My DN is the following:

```
OU=Organisation,DC=example,DC=com'
```

I've tried a lot of different filters, e.g.

```
(&(objectCategory=User)(&(objectCategory=organizationalUnit)(name=Users)))
```

I'm using PHP to make the Query. Is this possible in one query? Or what would be the solution to get only the User objects from all of the Users OU's?

Comment: Are you user entries under "ou=Users" identical to the ones under "ou=SharedMailboxes"? If so, you'll have to use multiple queries but if they are different you can build your search filter accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this from one LDAP search Request Against Microsoft Active Directory.

Some LDAP Server implementation will allow an [Extensible Match](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/ExtensibleMatch#section-ExtensibleMatch-SearchWithinTwoContainers) to do this, but [Microsoft Active Directory does not support this functionality.](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Microsoft%20Active%20Directory%20Extensible%20Match%20Rules)